# How to POST a request on Moodle using POSTMAN api tool

Tags: postman, moodle-api

I want to create an API request in Postman that creates a category in Moodle.
The following are the steps which I did in Moodle :

1. Enabled Web service
2. Created an External service and added core_course_create_categories function.
3. Enabled REST protocol
4. Created Token.

This is my POST URL:
http://localhost/test/moodle/webservice/rest/server.php?username=admin&password=Password@1&service=mycustomservice&name=CustomCategory&parent=1&idnumber=CSTM1&description=Desc

Under Authorization tab, I have selected **Bearer Token** and added the Token from Moodle web service.

When I send the request, I am getting **invalidtoken Invalid token - token not found** error.

Can anyone please suggest a solution for this

Moodle version: 3.4.8 and Postman version 7.6.0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not call API by GET Method.
In postman you have to call the API using POST method.
pass your token in form-data as wstoken.
call your function as wsfunction.

Check my Screenshot below.
[image]

Comment: Hi. I tried that. But displayed an error "invalidparameter Invalid parameter value detected". Please check the screenshot https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/9/6/e3f0957a364f455516fdb5ef7f7ba402-full.png

Comment: Hey, You are very close to your solution.
You just have to pass categories data in array formate.
I have updated my screenshot in the answer I have provided, please check it.

Comment: Hey, It worked. I had to remove "userid" from the body to make it work. Please check the new screenshot: https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/9/7/59fd14d7f33940ade575ce229dea5ffb-full.png. Also, I have noticed that you have included moodlewsrestformat in both Params and Body tab which I have not included. Is it required in the Params tab?

Comment: @Sarath moodlesrestformat is not required, actually, this parameter is used in old moodle version.
For API functions and how to pass its parameter, you can refer http://your_moodle_url/admin/webservice/documentation.php

If my answer helped you please mark it correct or do upvote it.

Thank you.

Comment: Also, can you please tell me how to pass parameters using raw Json format. I tried to pass the parameters as raw Json format. But it's throwing an error(invalidtoken Invalid token - token not found). Please check the screenshot below: https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/9/9/43025ba27f7ea20d05af38c6d674df09-full.png

Comment: There is no way in Moodle you can pass payload in raw json format.
You can use 3rd party moodle plugin to achieve this.
Bellow is a plugin which provides thing which you want, I didn't use it but you can give it a try.
https://moodle.org/plugins/webservice_restjson

Comment: Ok. I have created a POST request to enroll a user into a course which is working perfectly. Please see the screenshot below: https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/9/11/8414d090c8382c49a60c9a42493702cd-full.png.  Could you please tell me how to enroll multiple users in a single POST request?